# Possible technologies for Java client to server communication with primitive data?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee

What are the most common technologies for having a client java app communicate with a app server java app and what are their pros and cons?

Please tell me the magic words to search the web with.  I have heard '`Enterprise Java Bean`', '`RMI`', '`Web Services`' and '`JSON`'.

Simply where do I start looking so I can connect my `JavaSE` client to a `JavaEE` server application processing.

For now I would like to just transfer primitive data: `numbers`, `dates`, `Strings` etc.

Comment: the question is too broad, elaborate a bit. otherwise it could be voted to close. what you want to transfer to server?

Comment: I don't understand why this is closed.  Beginners need a place to find where to start with applications communicating over a network.  If you can rephrase this to be a valid question then please do so..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some good ones to consider:

- http://code.google.com/p/kryonet/ - Kryonet: fast, efficient binary serialisation
- http://code.google.com/p/protobuf/ - Protocol Buffers, Google's own data transfer library
- http://hessian.caucho.com/ - Hessian, yet another binary interchange library. Lots of support for different languages

You can also go for JSON / XML interchange formats. But they can be unwieldy and I think binary formats are better if you control both the client and the server (mainly for speed and network efficiency reasons).

Also, if you are interested in more of the low level stuff I strong recommend taking a look at Netty - I think it is pretty much the gold standard for Java network IO right now.

- https://netty.io/

Answer (score 0):

Your question is pretty broad, and it seems like you're having difficulty in knowing where to start. There are heaps and heaps of solutions out there for this. The key here is to keep things as simple as possible.

If I were you, I would check out http://dropwizard.codahale.com.

If you take the time to go through the examples and read some of the documentation you'll end up understanding all the basic concepts, even if you decide it isn't the best solution for your application.

FYI - Dropwizard is licensed under Apache License v2.

Answer (score 0):

You can have a look at [finagle](https://github.com/twitter/finagle), which "is an asynchronous network stack for the JVM that you can use to build asynchronous Remote Procedure Call (RPC) clients and servers in Java, Scala, or any JVM-hosted language. Finagle provides a rich set of tools that are protocol independent."